# Two different R versions and invoking of older R version

Tags: r, macos, version

I recently installed latest version of R(3.3.1) on my mac but somehow the R is still pointing to the old R version which I had. When R is invoked in command line it show the new version but on typing version in R environmnet the older(3.0.2) is shown.

What changes should be made so as to update to newer R version?
Also I deleted previous versions directories from Frameworks.

Additionally probably because of this issue I get an error when I start R studio.

```
ls /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/
3.3     Current

===========================

user1@my-mac:~$ R
Error in objects(db.pos, all.names = TRUE) : 
2 arguments passed to .Internal(ls) which requires 3

R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

....
....

Error in gzfile(file) : invalid 'encoding' argument
During startup - Warning message:
unable to restore saved data in .RData 

> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin10.8.0                
system         x86_64, darwin10.8.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2013                        
month          09                          
day            25                          
svn rev        63987                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
nickname       Frisbee Sailing
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, point `rstudio` to the newer version of `R` using the `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R` environment variable.

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/local/bin/R
```